# How to resolve this failed processing manifest error

Tags: android

Image here

[image]

How to resolve this error

Comment: you are missing something here. please check the theme you have applied exists in styles.xml

Comment: also try to add manifest or styles file here if possible.

Comment: First, remove the build folder under app and then check styles.xml is the NoActionBar theme is available or not.

Answer (score 2):

It has been a long time after this question has been asked. But I have been dealing with this problem and wanted to give my answer. Android studio does not give the exact reason why your manifest can not process building. Since it is a xml file you should go to your manifest file, go to redness and try to read the suggestion by android studio. In my case, I have deleted the string value, I thought I was not using it, yet I was using it in

```
android:label="@string/custom_app_dialog"
```

part. Then I added my string value back, it is all good now.

Answer (score 1):

If `AppTheme.NoActionBar` does not exist on your `styles.xml` then add this on `styles.xml`

```
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

This will help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting is in the `app\build\intermediates\packaged_manifests\debug` location, it a build error which consider the delet file as well.
go to `app\src\main` and in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file make sure to remove what's written in line no 22.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

when some time we will change the application logo without using any package that time we delete following folders :

- drawable-hdpi
- drawable-mdpi
- drawable-xhdpi
- drawable-xxhdpi
- vdrawable-xxxhdpi

in that case we are can't create pipmap folder
that time error: failed processing manifest
is raised

Answer (score 0):

For me it was error with the .package, since it is a reserved word in java. To change this, go to your capacitor.config file, and change it there to some other word and rebuild the app with

```
ionic build
ionic cap add android
ionic cap open android
```

Then go to build -> build apk

Answer (score -2):

Simple Answer,
delete your **release**,**build** folder